# How to run two instances of the same project in Xamarin for Mac?

Tags: mono, xamarin, osx-lion

I'm developing a Dispatcher Architectural Pattern in my Mac.
I have one solution with multiple Projects, there's one Project that I need to have multiple instances, in order to, simulate different clients. However Xamarin does not let me run more than one instance of that project. How can this be done ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to debug the application or just run multiple instances?

Comment: @SKall I just need to run multiple instances of that specific project within the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I figure it out. I just need to open the .exe with 'mono' in the Terminal. I can open as many 'mono' via Terminal as I want.
@Skall what must I do to debug the application with multiple instances ? Thanks.

Comment: You can open multiple XS instances with the 'open -n' command but unless you can attach VS to a running process I believe you would have to copy the source code to multiple directories as XS might have problems running multiple debug instances from the same source.

Answer (score 0):

Open Apple Script Editor and paste this command

```
do shell script "open -n /Applications/Xamarin\\ Studio.app/"
```

The export as an Application